# Julia: How to delte a column name starts with number in data frame

Tags: julia

I have data frame which a column name starts with number, I want to delete the column with the following code, but there is error:

```
delete!(features, [:3SsnPorchH])
```

UndefVarError: SsnPorchH not defined

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `:3SsnPorchH` is not correctly parsed as a symbol, but as follows:

```
julia> :(:3SsnPorchH)
:($(QuoteNode(3)) * SsnPorchH)
```

When a symbol cannot be  correctly parsed, it most often works to put the "name" into parentheses:

```
julia> :(3SsnPorchH)
:(3SsnPorchH)
```

Another thing you could do is using the `Symbol` constructor directly:

```
julia> Symbol("3SsnPorchH")
Symbol("3SsnPorchH")
```

(But I'm not sure if that's a good idea -- maybe you lose interning then.)

That being said, it's probably a good idea to give columns a name which is a valid Julia identifier.  This gives you construction using `DataFrame` with keyword arguments, and allows for certain [macros](http://www.david-anthoff.com/Query.jl/stable/gettingstarted.html) to identify variables with columns. You'll just have an easier time.